# I can't install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS due to black screen, and can't seem to get any of the previous responses to work

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, lts

Build:

- Intel i7-6700HQ (2.6GHz/3.5GHz) Quad Core Processor
- 6GB GDDR5 VRAM Nvidia® GeForce GTX 1060
- 64GB DDR4 2133MHz RAM (4 Dimm)
- 1TB M.2 (SSD) Solid State Drive (with Win10) and1TB Storage Hard
  Drive (target drive for Ubuntu)

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for the past few days and have run into nothing but trouble. I've tried installing it from a USB, but it cuts to black after hitting install on the GRUB menu (accompanied by a quiet bongo noise) and is completely unresponsive. I've tried nomodeset, nouveax.modeset=0 and other recommended fixes with no success. I was able to "install" after disabling UEFI, but the installation ended with an error message, and boots to the same black screen as before (doesn't even let me see the sign-in screen). Additionally, when trying to run the USB by itself, it freezes after I click "try ubuntu" and doesn't allow me to continue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you as to whether it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I would really recommend to install Ubuntu to your SSD alongside Windows so both systems can benefit from its speed.

Comment: @dessert I'll definitely consider doing that in the future, but for now, I just want to be able to cleanly install this, Arch or Kali without any issues. I'd rather not accidentally wipe windows off of my computer.

Comment: @karel ok, so I've tried making a minimal usb, and that didn't really do anything different (other than giving me a slightly different loading screen before it goes black). Tried using dd, didn't do anything different.